# rust creating a b"string" out of a String on the rhs of a match expression

Tags: rust

I am trying the following:

```
enum Payload {
    Text(String)
}

struct Message {
    payload: Payload
}

impl Message {
    fn snd (self) {

        let my_msg = match self.payload {
            Payload::Text(s) => s.into_bytes().as_slice() // error here!
        };
        println!("silly example: {}", my_msg);
    }
}

fn main () {
    let str = "hi".to_string();
    let pyld = Payload::Text(str);
    let msg = Message{payload: pyld};
    msg.snd();
}
```

but when i do i get the following error:

```
<anon>:13:33: 13:47 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
<anon>:13             Payload::Text(s) => s.into_bytes().as_slice()
```

**My question:** is there  a way to give slice value in the match statement instead of in the `println!` statement?

You can find the pen [here](http://is.gd/K95UCi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.into_bytes()` consumes `s` and produces a `Vec<u8>`. It is not stored anywhere and so goes out of scope immediately.

You have called `.as_slice()` on that, which produces `&[u8]`, a reference into that object. However, as stated, it’s immediately going out of scope and so “the borrowed value does not live long enough”.

The solution is not to consume the payload in any of this but to take references all the way:

```
let my_msg = match self.payload {
    Payload::Text(ref s) => s.as_bytes(),
};
```

The `ref s` instead of `s` means that it takes a reference to the `String` (`s` is of type `&String` rather than `String`), and then we use `as_bytes(&self) -> &[u8]` instead of `into_bytes(self) -> Vec<u8>`.